# Export/Import Tasks From/In TFS 2010

Tags: tfsintegrationplatform

I need to export all tasks, including details of each task, to another TFS.

How can I achieve this with least effort.

Thanks.

Comment: How many team projects are involved here?  If it is just one team project, there's a relatively simple solution.  If it's multiple, it gets a bit harder.

Comment: @Robaticus, what is the relatively simple solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [TFS Integration Platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/) for this.